# How to get the html of a selection

Tags: html, jquery

I thought it is a simple problem, but it is not!
Below you find my current code, which works fine for selected text. But for example, if an image is included in the selection, it returns only the name of the image, but not the tag with the src info.
I tried several solutions, but no one was solved for my problem.
I also tried

```
var temp = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();
```

But I could not find out, how to get the raw html code with this node object.
What I want, is the raw html code of the selection. no matter if the html is incomplete due the selection or not.

Thanks for your help!

```
function getSelectionTextAndContainerElement() {
   var text = "", containerElement = null;
   if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      alert(sel);
      if (sel.rangeCount) {
        var node = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
        containerElement = node.nodeType == 1 ? node : node.parentNode;
        text = sel.toString();
      }
   } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
           document.selection.type != "Control") {
       var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
       containerElement = textRange.parentElement();
       alert(textRange);
       text = textRange.text;
   }
   return {
       text: text,
       containerElement: containerElement
   };
}
```

As requested a html example, but the code could be different from time to time!

```
        <p><img alt="devil" height="23" src="http://www.domain.eu/typo3conf/ext/simpleblog/Resources/Public/CKEDITOR/plugins/smiley/images/devil_smile.png" title="devil" width="23" /> Ist doch ganz nett, oder?</p>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="tx_simpleblog_fesblog[editBlog][subBlog]" value="1" />
    </div>
```

My test case is currently, to select from the "devil_smile image to the end of "Ist doch nett, oder?

Comment: Can you post the HTML so we can work a solution for you?

Comment: Added it above!

Comment: Have you tried `.inner/outerHTML`?

Comment: @Joel
With `cloneContent's` and`temp.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node){` I got with `node.otherHTML` the img tag but not the text. Only with `sel.getRangeAt(0)` I am able to get the text .